# AWS/Aurora : is it possible to know if the slaves are correctly used

Tags: kotlin, jdbi, amazon-aurora

I have a working aurora cluster with a master and a slave.

I use the following code to create a datasource

```
    val jdbi: Jdbi by lazy {
        val ds = MariaDbDataSource()
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql:aurora://cluster_endpoint/db")
        ds.user = System.getenv("DB_USERNAME")
        ds.setPassword(System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))

        val jdbi = Jdbi.create(ds)
        jdbi.installPlugin(SqlObjectPlugin())
        jdbi.installPlugin(KotlinSqlObjectPlugin())
        jdbi
    }
```

Then, when I am in a readonly operation I do the following :

```
jdbi.open().use { handle ->
    handle.setReadOnly(true)
    ...
}
```

How can I be sure that when I do that, queries / connections are correctly routed to the slave ?

I have tried to log the db instance connection

```
val url = handle.connection.getMetaData().getURL()
val connServer = url.substring(url.indexOf("//") + 2 , url.indexOf("."));
```

But this always gives me the URL of the cluster...

Is there a way to know if we are talking to the slave or to the master ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some more digging, I find the answer burried in mariadb doc at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-21-aurora-monitor/#how-aurora-is-monitored (emphasis is mine)

```
SELECT @@aurora_server_id, server_id FROM information_schema.replica_host_status WHERE session_id = 'MASTER_SESSION_ID';
```

**The node which returns a row with two identical fields is the master.** All other nodes are read-only replicas and will be labeled as slave servers.

So in kotlin, with jdbi, you can do :

```
        //https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-21-aurora-monitor/#how-aurora-is-monitored
        val sql = "SELECT @@aurora_server_id, server_id FROM information_schema.replica_host_status WHERE session_id = 'MASTER_SESSION_ID'"
        val serverIds = handle.select(sql)
                .map { rs, _ -> Pair(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)) }
                .single()
        val serverId = serverIds.first
        val isMaster = serverId == serverIds.second
        val masterOrSlave = if (isMaster) "the master" else "a slave"
        Logger.getLogger(this.javaClass.name).debug("Connected to db instance $serverId which is $masterOrSlave")
```